# Идентичны ли данные проверки? if($_POST) и if(isset($_POST))

Tags: php, if

Хочу уточнить: данная конструкция `if($_POST)` означает - если  существует $_POST?

Идентична ли эта конструкция вот этой конструкции `if(isset($_POST))`, если нет, то чем они отличаются?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Не идентична.

```
$var=0;
if($var)echo "true";else echo "false";         //fasle
if(isset($var))echo "true";else echo "false";  //true

unset($var);
if($var)echo "true";else echo "false";   //E_NOTICE: [type: 8] -- Undefined variable 
if(isset($var))echo "true";else echo "false";   //false
```

Очевидно, что функцией `isset` пользоваться безопаснее.

Answer (score 3):

Интересно, что никто из отвечателей не обратил внимание на исключительность переменной, использованной автором.

И если отвечать на конкретный вопрос, а не просто разглагольствовать о приведении типов, то ответ будет такой:

- `if(isset($_POST))` использовать бессмысленно, поскольку этот массив всегда существует.
- `if($_POST)` можно использовать для проверки, содержится ли в этом массиве какое-либо значение. Никаких нотисов эта проверка не выведет.

При этом следует учитывать, что пустые чекбоксы не передаются на сервер, то есть, в теории массив может быть пустым и после отправки формы.

Поэтому для определения факта отправки формы методом POST, следует использовать код

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое - это проверка на существование, а второе смотрит значение переменной и на его основе выполняется проверка. То есть переменная может существовать, но значением его может быть, например, `false`. В таком случае `isset($_POST['key'])` вернет `true`, а `$_POST['key']` вернет `false`.
Если имеется ввиду конкретно массив `$_POST`, а не какой-либо его элемент, то массив `$_POST` существует всегда и `isset($_POST)` вернет всегда `true`. Если проверяем существование элемента массива таким образом `if($_POST['key'])`, то нужно учитывать, что если значением окажется пустая строка или '0' (что отвратительнее всего), то проверка вернет `false`. строка '0' преобразуется в число 0, затем в `false` и мы получаем `if(false)`. Погугли ещё конструкцию `empty()`.

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция `if ($_POST)` эквивалентна `if (!empty($_POST))`. Кроме того, первый вариант вызовет NOTICE-сы (в вышеприведённом ответе, это видно).

Данная конструкция (`if ($_POST)`) применима в том случае, если объектом проверки является функция/метод (если, конечно, функция что-то возвращает). К примеру,

```
if (foo($var))
```

, либо с присвоением

```
if (!$var_1 = foo($var_2)) {
  /* тело условия */
}
```

если `foo($var_2)` возвратит `'', null, false`, либо `0` ([**Таблица сравнения типов в PHP**](http://php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php)), то выполнится тело условия, в противном же случае, `$var_1` будет содержать результат выполнения функции `foo`.

В PHP 5.5 станет возможным [**применить**](http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/chto-nas-zhdjot-v-php-5.5) empty к функциям/методам.